# Identifying a connector on engine block

Tags: subaru, part-identification, outback

I have 2005 Subaru Outback 3.0R H6.

Today, out of the blue I've got P0500 Vehicle Speed Sensor "A" code.

One of the symptoms of this code might be exposed wires somewhere. I checked the wires under the hood and found that on top of engine block there used to be a mice nest and they chewed one wire which is now a bit exposed. However, I have no idea what this cable is and what it does.

Could you please help me identify it so I can do more research about it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the factory service manual specific to your Subaru vehicle including trouble shooting error codes and wiring diagrams over
@ https://jdmfsm.info/Auto/Japan/Subaru/Legacy_Outback/2005/.

This manual describes P0500 on page 2958 as related to either the ABS warning light OR a wiring problem, I've pasted the section below.

For part and loom identification electronic catalogues such as parts.subaru.com usually have handy diagrams.

> ENGINE (DIAGNOSTICS)(H6DO) > Diagnostic Procedure with Diagnostic Trouble Code (DTC)
>
> DTC P0500 VEHICLE SPEED SENSOR “A”
>
> DTC DETECTING CONDITION:
>
> Immediately at fault recognition
>
> CAUTION:
> After repairing or replacing the defective part, perform the Clear Memory Mode  and Inspection Mode .
>
> STEP  CHECK   YES NO
> 1.CHECK DTC OF ABS.
>
> Check DTC of ABS.
>
> Is DTC of ABS displayed?
>
> Y: Perform the diagnosis according to DTC.
>
> N: Repair poor contact in ECM connector.

Answer (score 2):

P0500 on the H6 engine is, as you say, a Vehicle Speed Sensor. Check your ABS sensors on each of the front wheels.

Here's the usual cause for a P0500 error;

[image]

Check the ABS tone wheel on each front wheel, plus the connector wiring to it. The sensors themselves are usually pretty reliable unless they're damaged by removing the hub.

Comment: ABS sensors look okay. I've cleared the error and drove for about 40km and it hasn't returned yet. However, I would still like to figure out what connector got chewed by mice. Any chance you can identify from the picture?

Comment: I don't have a H6 manual to hand, but that looks like a Knock Sensor. If it is, there will be an identical sensor on the other bank of the engine for the left-hand three cylinders. A broken knock sensor sets a specific code - e.g P0325 (I think the H6 can set one of two codes, depending on which sensor is faulty). Changing it out takes about 30 minutes - most of that is removing the inlet manifold. My inclination would be to wrap it in Loom Harness Tape and leave it until it's obviously failed.